# owncloud: change or access URL of shared folder

Tags: owncloud

I installed owncloud on my server.* There is a folder I have shared, so I got a URL like:

```
mydomain.com/owncloud/index.php/s/randomKey1
```

I sent this URL to my friends.** After a few days, I accidentally unclicked and then reclicked the "share" checkbox, so a new URL was generated for this folder:

```
mydomain.com/owncloud/index.php/s/randomKey2
```

Is it possible to change the URL back to `.../randomKey1`? Or can I somehow access `.../randomKey1` and create a redirect to `.../randomKey2`?

---

* I followed a step-by-step tutorial, so I have no idea what happened.

** I created a QR-code out of this URL and included this qr-code into a little booklet I have printed, so I can't just "resend" the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I am aware of would be to edit the table 'oc_share' on your server.

You can do this directly on the command line on your server, something like this should work for you:-

```
mysql -u dbUserName -pDBUserPassWord
use owncloud;
select * from oc_share;
```

This will show something like:-

```
mysql> select * from oc_share;
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| id | share_type | share_with | uid_owner | parent | item_type | item_source | item_target     | file_source | file_target            | permissions | stime      | accepted | expiration | token           | mail_send |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------+-----------+
|  2 |          3 | NULL       | user      |   NULL | folder    | 4047        | /4047           |        4047 | /share                 |           1 | 1426869728 |        0 | NULL       | randomkey2      |         0 |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

In which case you could reset the value of the 'token' column thus:-

```
UPDATE `owncloud`.`oc_share` SET `token`='randomkey1' WHERE `id`='2';
```

Hopefully that should work for you.

If you have phpmyadmin installed on your server, then you can use that to edit the table.

**Warning:** I haven't tested this and you should back up your DB before trying it.